# property does not exist React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass a parameter from one component to another component.

i am trying to pass CurrentStateUpdate from onboardingFooter to onboarding without success

....is some unnecessary code

onboarding

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, FlatList, Image, Text, View} from 'react-native';


const Onboarding = ({list}) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={list}
      horizontal
      pagingEnabled
      onMomentumScrollEnd={updateCurrentState}
      contentContainerStyle={{height: windowHeight * 0.75}}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return (
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Image
              source={item.image}
              style={{height: '75%', width: windowWidth}}
            />
            .....
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Onboarding;
```

onboardingFooter

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const OnboardingFooter = ({list}) => {
  const [currentSate, setCurrentState] = useState(0);
  const updateCurrentState = e => {
    const contentOffsetX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const currentSate = Math.round(contentOffsetX / windowWidth);
    setCurrentState(currentSate);
  };
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: windowHeight * 0.25,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
      }}>
      ......
  );
};

export default OnboardingFooter;
```

onboardingScreen

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {ONBOARDING} from '../data/onboarding';
import Onboarding from '../components/ Onboarding/Onboarding';
import OnboardingFooter from '../components/ Onboarding/OnboardingFooter';

const OnboardingScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Onboarding list={ONBOARDING} />
      <OnboardingFooter list={ONBOARDING} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default OnboardingScreen;
```

I tried to cast from onboardingScreen without success